# Получиться ли добавить свой микроконтроллер(STM) в platformio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, arduino, stm32, stm32cubeide

Получиться ли добавить свой микроконтроллер(STM) в platformio?

Answer (score 0):

Да, может немного не то, но получилось добавить и писать код просто в VSCode без плагина platformIO. после конфигурирования микроконтроллера в CubeMX я по этой инструкции (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxQw5_7yI8Q настройка набора инструментов для создания проектов STM32 под Windows в VSCode для программирования и отладки того же устройства.) его добавил в VSCode и смог писать код

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)